# Существует ли аналог функции cin.peek() в си?

Tags: c, вывод, ввод

Существует ли аналог функции cin.peek() в си? Или в си придется обязательно читать символ из потока, а потом возвращать его?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Аналога нету. Надо писать самому:

```
/* return the next character from stdin without consuming it */
int peekchar(void) {
    int c = getchar();
    if (c != EOF) ungetc(c, stdin);  /* puts it back */    
    return c;
}
```

http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/aspnes/pinewiki/C(2f)InputOutput.html

```
int fpeek(FILE *stream){    
    int c = fgetc(stream);
    ungetc(c, stream);
    return c;
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082743/c-equivalent-to-fstreams-peek